# Kubernetes - How to get client IP behind loadbalancer?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

How get client IP from nginx ingress load blanacer? I've tried setting `use proxy protocol` and `externalTrafficPolicy` but still it doesn't show client IP.

Apache logs `10.0.0.225` for each http request. I'm not sure what IP that is, it doesn't seem to be pod's
IP or node IP.

httpd service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: httpd
  labels:
    app: httpd-service
  namespace: test-web-dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: httpd
  ports:
    - name: port-80
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
    - name: port-443
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 443
  sessionAffinity: "ClientIP"
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 10800
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

ingress-lb:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  use-proxy-protocol: 'true'
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
```

In Apache I've  configured the following logging settings:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
CustomLog "logs/ssl_access_log" combined env=!forwarded
CustomLog "logs/ssl_access_log" proxy env=forwarded
```

Answer (score 3):

You should get the origin IP in the `X-Forwarded-For` header, this is a default config for nginx-ingress: [forwarded-for-header](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#forwarded-for-header)

This is configured in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/)

Comment: where do I configure that?

Comment: I don't see `X-Forwarded-For` in that configmap. What's the key and value I should add?

Comment: No I haven't yet.